# why does mount ignore effective user id

Tags: linux

I'm wondering why my version of mount appears to ignore the effective user ID...

I have this C program owned by root with permission u+s:

```
int main() {
    execl("/bin/mount", "/bin/mount", "/mnt/abc", (char *)0);
}
```

When a regular user runs it, it complains about not being root. I can work around it like this:

```
int main() {
    setuid(0);
    execl("/bin/mount", "/bin/mount", "/mnt/abc", (char *)0);
}
```

I read that bash changes the effective uid to the real uid as a safety feature. (see [Calling a script from a setuid root C program - script does not run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556194/calling-a-script-from-a-setuid-root-c-program-script-does-not-run-as-root)) However, I don't see why mount should do that. Does anyone know?

My mount version is:

> mount from util-linux 2.29.2 (libmount 2.29.2: selinux, btrfs, assert, debug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `mount` is designed to run as suid root.

```
$ ls -l /bin/mount
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44200 Mar  6 13:31 /bin/mount
   ^
```

CDs or floppy drives would typically have the `user` option set in fstab to allow non-root users to access removable media. `mount` was made SUID root to support this, and it therefore checks the real UID to determine what you're allowed to do.